# Keyboard unresponsive after textarea / input touch

Tags: salesforce1-app, html, ios

I have a `textarea` within a VF page, as part of an app I'm working on for Salesforce1.

When I touch the `textarea` on an iOS device, it freezes. The keyboard stays up, the cursor flashes inside the `textarea` but I can't enter any text.

This is only happening on iOS devices, Android and Windows phones work fine.

At the moment, [it's a known issue with Salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC), but as they have no plan to address it until Spring '15, I'm wondering has anyone here seen this issue or had any joy finding a workaround of some sort.